# ModuleNotFoundError when activating venv virtual environment in a python CGI script

Tags: python, pytorch, cgi, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I just started using the huggingface transformers library and have been experimenting with it via Pytorch and venv.

If I activate the venv virtual environment from a shell, it works just fine.
However, not if I activate it in a Python CGI script, like so:

```
# Importing libraries for virtual environment
import subprocess

# Defining function for activating/deactivating virtual environment
def activate_virtual_environment():

    # Build the path to the activation script
    activation_script = f"/xampp/htdocs/cgi_bin/env/Scripts/activate"

    # Activate the virtual environment using subprocess
    subprocess.run([activation_script], shell=True)

def deactivate_virtual_environment():
    # Deactivate the virtual environment using subprocess
    subprocess.run(["deactivate"], shell=True)

# Activating virtual environment
activate_virtual_environment()

# Importing 'pipeline' 
from transformers import pipeline
```

If I activate the virtual environment like this, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘transformers’`, when the script is executed.

The path to the virtual environment is definitely correct, what am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the process model for virtualenv activate scripts.

The 'activate' script in a virtualenv works by modifying environment variables in the shell process that is executing its commands, notably PATH and VIRTUAL_ENV.

The python subprocess module runs the requested program as a separate subprocess, so the environment variable modifications affect only the process that is actually processing the commands in the 'activate' script.

Thus, you cannot use the python subprocess module to achieve what you are trying to do.

The simplest complete solution is to write a small wrapper script that activates the virtualenv and then runs the python interpreter with your python program, which no longer needs to worry about doing the activation or subprocess thing at all.

A simpler solution on Linux, would be to modify the shebang of your python script to point to the python binary inside the virtualenv, but I'm guessing from the '/Scripts/' part in your code that you are on Windows, so I'm not sure how that translates to Windows.

The first option is complete in the sense that it also sets the VIRTUAL_ENV environment variable whereas the second does not.  Whether that's important or not for you depends on whether your python code, or the other python code you are importing, relies on that environment variable or not.